# ffmpeg AVStream::codecpar is null

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm trying to make a simple audio decoder by using libav, and I encounter a problem.
I cannot get AVCodecParameters from AVStream, codepar always is null.

here is my code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s input_file > output_file\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  const int out_channels = 2, out_samples = 512, sample_rate = 44100;

  int max_buffer_size;

  // register supported formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // allocate empty format context
  // provides methods for reading input packets
  AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

  // determine input file type and initialize format context
  if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error: avformat_open_input()\n");
      exit(1);
  }

  // determine supported codecs for input file streams and add
  // them to format context
  if (avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: avformat_find_stream_info()\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  AVCodec* codec = NULL;
  int stream = 0;

  // find audio stream in format context
    
  fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", fmt_ctx->nb_streams);
  for (int i = 0; i < fmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
    AVCodecParameters* avCodecParameters = NULL;
    avCodecParameters = fmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar;
    if(!avCodecParameters){
      fprintf(stderr, "error: CodecParameters\n");// always fail here
      exit(1);
    }
    if(avCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO){
      stream = i;
      codec = avcodec_find_decoder(avCodecParameters->codec_id);
      if (!codec) {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: avcodec_find_decoder()\n");
          exit(1);
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  if (stream == fmt_ctx->nb_streams) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: no audio stream found\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For the input file format, I have tried .wav and .m4a file

and the output always is

```
1
error: CodecParameters
```

Dose anyone has the same problem?

How to solve it?

thanks!

Comment: Don't exit on `!avCodecParameters` The first stream may be null. by the second stream may be what you are looking for.

Comment: How did you solve?

Comment: Make sure you don't have conflicting library versions.  Cmake was not playing nice with my cross compile and I was pulling in old libraries (libavcodec, etc) from a standard path instead of my custom path. I didn't realize this and just happened to have both sets of libraries on my embedded system. When I was running I thought it was using my updated libraries but it wasn't. My error ended up being that AVCodecParameters* in my AVStream* was null, causing a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code does not explicitly convert `const AVCodecParameters` to `AVCodecParameters` discarded `const` resulting in a warning. Try like this:

`AVCodecParameters* avCodecParameters = NULL;`